# How Django signal receiver should handle errors?

Tags: python, django, signals, messaging

Cite from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#receiver-functions):

> ...look at the **kwargs argument. All signals send keyword arguments,
>   and may change those keyword arguments at any time. In the case of
>   request_finished, it’s documented as sending no arguments, which means
>   we might be tempted to write our signal handling as
>   my_callback(sender).
>
> This would be wrong – in fact, Django will throw an error if you do
>   so. That’s because at any point arguments could get added to the
>   signal and your receiver must be able to handle those new arguments.

I don't get it. Why 'arguments could be added at any time', isn't interfaces in programs exist to be constant and everybody should be aware of them? Or does these words mean, that every receiver must always fail silently? Because it is obvious if, sender would randomly change interface, receivers will fail and throw errors.

> This would be wrong – in fact, Django will throw an error if you do
>   so.

Throwing errors is wrong when using signals or what did they meant?

Answer (score 2):

In Python and especially in Django, it is common to program API's (or more precisely, the functions that expose the API's) in a way that when given additional parameters, they can still operate instead of crashing.

In your particular situation- consider a signal handler like:

```
def (sender, param1, param2):
    pass
```

Lets say you have some version X.Y of Django where this handler works perfectly. Then you realise that Django has been updated to X.Z and one thing in the changelog was that signals now get given a fourth keyword arg (`param3`).

Would you rather go through you entire codebase and change handlers to:

```
def handler(sender, param1, param2, param3):
    pass
```

...or would it have been better to program all handlers like:

```
def handler(sender, param1, param2, **kwargs):
    pass
```

?

This kind of design is also useful when your functions are supposed to relay the params to other functions:

```
def func(*args,**kwargs):
    # do something
    other_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

There is a caveat though: this kind of API design is reasonably when acting on params is voluntary. Consider a (naive) example like the following "sum" API.

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
```

Then in the next version the sum function suddenly starts to get more params: a,b,c. A function like the following would probably cause hard to track bugs:

```
def sum(a,b,**kwargs):
    return a+b
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that is just telling you to be sure you always include the `**kwargs` argument. So you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Throwing errors is wrong when using signals or what did they meant?

They only mean that the `**kwargs` is required when you call signal receiver function. Throwing errors when using signals is not wrong a priori. In conclusion, remind to always include the kwargs when you need to define a receiver function, as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#receiver-functions) says:

```
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Request finished!")
```